# In PostgresSQL how to write a query returning multiple rows and columns

Tags: postgresql

My original query was like this:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*), user_id FROM user_sessions WHERE company_id=companies.id GROUP BY user_id) as user_sessions
FROM companies
```

Which comes back with this error:

`error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

I found a way past that error with this:

```
SELECT *,
ARRAY (SELECT COUNT(*), user_id FROM user_sessions WHERE company_id=companies.id GROUP BY user_id) as user_sessions
FROM companies
```

But then it has this error:

`error: subquery must return only one column`

If I remove either `COUNT(*)` or `user_id` from the returned columns it works, however I need both sets of data.  How do I return more than one column in a sub-query like this?

Comment: Replace `COUNT(*), user_id` with `ARRAY[COUNT(*), user_id]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this in the future, tested the best way to dot this is what @Matt mentioned in the comments above:

Replace `COUNT(*), user_id` with `ARRAY[COUNT(*), user_id]`

Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I guess a join should do the trick:

```
select * from
companies
join
( select count(*), company_id, user_id
  from user_sessions
  group by (company_id, user_id)
) as user_sessions
on companies.id = company_id
```